# bower proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, bower

is there a way to configure bower not only to use a proxy but ignore the proxy configuration for some domains?

I have the problem, that I will run an internal bower registry for our own developed components. For that repository I would like to ignore the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For info, in your `.bowerrc` file you can add a no-proxy attribute. I don't know since when it is supported but it works on bower 1.7.4

**.bowerrc :**

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components", 
  "proxy": "http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "https-proxy":"http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "no-proxy":"myserver.mydomain.com"
}
```

`.bowerrc` should be located in the root folder of your Javascript project, the folder in which you launch the bower command.  You can also have it in your home folder (`~/.bowerrc`).

Comment: The .bowerrc file must be placed in which folder?

Comment: The root folder of your javascript project. The folder in which you launch the bower command.

Comment: You can have the file in `~/.bowerrc` as well, it doesn't need to be in the project's folder.

Answer (score 76):

Edit your .bowerrc file ( should be next to your bower.json file ) and add the wanted proxy configuration

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
```

Comment: where are either of these files in ubuntu?

Comment: If the file is not present, create it in the same folder as bower.json. Also, it should be valid JSON, so wrap it with {}. See @eastolfi's answer.

Comment: You can also use this in your home folder as a global setting: in ~/

Comment: This should be the selected answer, as per [the docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/) this is the correct way to configure Bower for these cases.

Comment: This should be selected as answer. worked like a charm

Comment: Upvoted - I was already using CNTLM (as the accepted answer suggests), however I still had to create the `.bowerrc` to tell bower which port the proxy was listening on, thanks :)

Comment: Watch out for when this gets checked-into Git and runs on your build server which doesn't use the proxy.

Answer (score 27):

I had ETIMEDOUT error, and after putting

```
{
  "proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
  "https-proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
}
```

just worked. I don't know if you have something wrong in the .bowerrc or ECONNRESET can't be solved with this, but I hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 14):

I struggled with this from behind a proxy so I thought I should post what I did. Below one is worked for me.

-> "export HTTPS_PROXY=(yourproxy)"

Comment: Adding HTTPS_PROXY to my system variables in windows worked great, Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The key for me was adding an extra line,     "strict-ssl": false

Create .bowerrc on root folder, and add the following,

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components", // If you change this, your folder named will change within dependecies. EX) Vendors instead of bower_components.
  "proxy": "http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "https-proxy":"http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "strict-ssl": false 
}
```

Best of luck for the people still stuck on this.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to configure an exclusion to the proxy settings, but a colleague of mine had an create solution for that particular problem.
He installed a local proxy server called [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/). That server supports ntlm authentication and exclusions to the general proxy settings. A perfect match.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your local project open the .bowerrc that contains:

```
{
   "directory": "bower_components"
 }
```

and add the following code-line:

```
{
   "directory": "bower_components",
  "proxy": "http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "https-proxy":"http://yourProxy:yourPort"
}
```

bower version: 1.7.1

Cheers

Comment: I found this solution a lot of times, but in my case I don't have proxy so.. I don't understand why I have to set a proxy definition in .bowerrc

Comment: Daniel, if you are not behind a proxy, just live the  .bowerrc as it is...

Answer (score 2):

Add the below entry to your `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
  "https-proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
}
```

Also if your password contains any special character URL-encode it
Eg: replace the @ character with %40

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows? Just set the environment variable http_proxy...

```
set http_proxy=http://your-proxy-address.com:port
```

... and bower will pick this up.  Rather than dealing with a unique config file in your project folder - right?  (side-note: when-the-F! will windows allow us to create a .file using explorer? c'mon windows!)

Answer (score 0):

create .bowerrc file in you home directory and adding this to the file worked for me

{

```
 "directory": "bower_components",
 "proxy": "http://youProxy:yourPort",
  "https-proxy":"http://yourProxy:yourPort"
}
```

Answer (score -6):

add in .bowerrc

```
{SET HTTP_PROXY= http://HOST:PORT,SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://HOST:PORT}
```

In NPM, you must to execute in console this:

```
npm --proxy http://Host:Port install
```