# bower behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, bower

`bower install` behind a proxy fails in timeout with the following settings (some set are useless...) :

```
git config --global http.proxy fr-proxy.example.com:3128
git config --global https.proxy fr-proxy.example.com:3128

export http_proxy=http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128
export https_proxy=http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128

npm config set proxy http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128
npm config set https-proxy http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have also tried an install/uninstall of bower and a `bower clean cache`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bower proxy configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359887/bower-proxy-configuration)

Comment: Good compilation of everything that we have to do to get everything working! Great work! :+1:

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Edit your .bowerrc file and add the wanted proxy configuration:

```
{
    "proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
    "https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

If working behind an authenticated proxy, user and password should be included like this:

```
{
    "proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
    "https-proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
}
```

Usually, the .bowerrc is next to the bower.json. And if there is no .bowerrc file near the bower.json file, you can create one by yourself.

Comment: Just create the .bowerrc file at your user directory *~/.bowerrc*

Comment: You can also do this on Windows in C:\Users\{Username}\.bowerrc

Comment: @rmic how to find <host> and <port> in windows

Comment: @Kartheeks not sure to understand your question. The <host> and <port> are the proxy ones.

Comment: @rmic I mean to say what values we need to place in `<host>`, `<port>` from the above code. Is it `localhose ---> host` and `8080 ---> port` (or) can we see those numbers from "cmd/terminal"

Comment: @Kartheeks, they are just the host and port for your proxy. I can't tell you what they are and do not know if you can find them by your terminal ;-)

Comment: NOTICE the use of http:// in https-proxy. It did the trick for me – as mentioned [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23288312/4420532)

Answer (score 30):

I have problem with `bower list` command, which was caused by the fact that bower use `git` with `git://` URLs to get the list of remote GitHub repositories, but `git://` protocol is blocked by our corporate firewall. In order to solve this problem in addition to setting environment variables, I have to add extra configurations to git too. Here's full list of commands I have to execute (remember to replace proxy host and port with yours):

```
# set proxy for command line tools
export HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128
export https_proxy=http://localhost:3128

# add configuration to git command line tool
git config --global http.proxy http://localhost:3128
git config --global https.proxy http://localhost:3128
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
```

Standard environment variables in Bash are uppercased, for proxy those are `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`, but some tools expect them to be in lowercase, bower is one of those tools. This is why I prefer to have proxy set in 2 cases: lower and upper.

Bower is using git to get packages from GitHub, this is why configuration keys need to be added to git too. `http.proxy` and `https.proxy` are proxy settings and should point to your proxy. Last but not least you need to tell git not to use `git://` protocol, because it may be blocked by firewall. You need to replace it with standard `http://` protocol. Someones suggest to use `https://` instead of `git://` like following: `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`, but I was getting `Connection reset by peer` error, so I'm using `http://`, which is working fine for me.

At home I don't use any proxy and don't have corporate firewall, so I prefer to switch back to "normal" no-proxy settings. Here's how I do it:

```
# remove proxy environment variables
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
# remove git configurations

git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset url."http://".insteadOf
```

I'm not very good at remembering things, so I would never remember all those commands. On top of this I'm lazy and would not want to type those long commands by hand. This is why I was creating functions to set and unset proxy settings. Here's 2 functions I've added to my `.bashrc` file after some aliases definitions:

```
set_proxy() {
    export HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
    export HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
    # some tools uses lowercase env variables
    export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128
    export https_proxy=http://localhost:3128
    # config git
    git config --global http.proxy http://localhost:3128
    git config --global https.proxy http://localhost:3128
    git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
}
unset_proxy() {
    unset HTTP_PROXY
    unset HTTPS_PROXY
    unset http_proxy
    unset https_proxy
    git config --global --unset http.proxy
    git config --global --unset https.proxy
    git config --global --unset url."http://".insteadOf
}
```

Now when I need to set proxy, I just execute `set_proxy` command, and to unset `unset_proxy` command. With the help of Bash's autocomplete I don't even need to type those commands, but let tab complete them for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me. `bower search` and `bower install` were working fine, but `bower list` was a no-go.  One thing to note though, if your network has multiple proxy servers, make sure you use the same proxy here as you do in `~/.bowerrc` or you'll get 503's and/or connection timeouts!

Answer (score 6):

My script (using git bash on Windows) for setting proxy was executed by a different user from the one I was using for bower. The environment variables were not taken into account.

So the following setting is sufficient, as specified in other answers:

```
export http_proxy=http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128
export https_proxy=http://fr-proxy.example.com:3128
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Linux or OS X try the following command
`bash
http_proxy='proxy server' https_proxy='proxy server' bower`