# bower through a proxy

Tags: npm, bower

I'm trying to use bower through a corporate proxy. I read [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/467#issuecomment-21482598) that I should add some stuff to my .bowerrc file. I did and now instead of getting a not found error, I'm getting ECONNRESET.

npm works fine.

Any suggestions?

errors:

last one:

```
Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap failed: tunneling socket could
not be established, cause=Parse Error
```

and a bunch of these:

```
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery faile
d with ECONNRESET, retrying in 12.4s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-mock
s failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 9.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-scen
ario failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 15.0s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-rout
e failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 15.7s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-sani
tize failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 11.6s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-cook
ies failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 9.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-reso
urce failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 25.6s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular fail
ed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 26.3s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-mock
s failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 24.8s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/json3 failed
 with ECONNRESET, retrying in 20.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap fa
iled with ECONNRESET, retrying in 17.2s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-cook
ies failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 16.8s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery faile
d with ECONNRESET, retrying in 18.0s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-sani
tize failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 22.6s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/es5-shim fai
led with ECONNRESET, retrying in 26.3s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-scen
ario failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 22.7s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-rout
e failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 20.9s
bower ECONNRESET
```

Comment: could you please post your .bowerrc file?

Comment: Here is the answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750804/bower-calls-blocked-by-corporate-proxy

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
npm --proxy username:password@proxy:8080[/someproxyjs.pac] install -g bower
```

**Attention:**
Should be start with http and replace your account username:password.
Some of proxy maybe automatic script please fill full replace `[/someproxyjs.pac]`