# Why is Bower showing ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, bower

I install bower

`npm install -g bower`

`bower --version`

1.3.9

`bower search jquery`

bower ENOTFOUND     Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/jquery failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

It is a fresh install, with nothing special happening. I am not behind a proxy, and other libraries such as grunt or npm work with no problems. So why specifically is bower unable to reach the internet?

I am at step one of a Bower install tutorial. There is nothing I can add to this question other than I am brand new to Bower and it does not work as expected.

I got rid of git / node with a complete re-install.  All set up again, and back to this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750804/bower-calls-blocked-by-corporate-proxy - His example is similar to mine, but I am not on a proxy. Like him, bower does not actually make any kind of request to the internet.

Comment: try again? maybe bower registry server was down? can you ping the server? what do you get when you visit the URI you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am deeply ashamed.

It was comodo auto-sandbox feature. I am not sure if there was an update at some point recently, but having that enabled blocked bower. No warnings, no apparent logs, no notifications. Having never altered comodo, it took me off guard.