# Global Bower .bowerrc file location to enable proxy

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2013, bower

Since I have the same issue as in [Bower calls blocked by corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750804/bower-calls-blocked-by-corporate-proxy) I have created a **config.bowerrc** file in AppData/Roaming/... as shown below:

[image]

with the following in it - edited with my own settings:

```
{
  "directory": "library",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
  "proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/",
  "https-proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/"
}
```

However, this does not seem to work as I still get the following message in Visual Studio:

[image]

Where should the global **config.bowerrc** file which sets the proxy be located?

Comment: Just an FYI, there is a typo in your .bowerrc JSON. Remove the extra comma at the end or bower will throw an unable to parse error. (Ran into this by way of copy-paste.)

Comment: @bdetweiler Thanks! I removed it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The name of the bower [configuration file](http://bower.io/docs/config/) should be `.bowerrc`
It can be located in one of the following:

- Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
- All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
- .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (`%USERPROFILE%`)
- bowerrc (without the dot) file located in `%APPDATA%/bower/config`

The config is obtained by merging multiple configurations by this order of importance. Local .bowerrc file has the highest precedence while the global one has the lowest (CLI arguments and environment variables has higher precedence than the bowerrc file).

Comment: Renamed the file to .bowerrc.txt and placed it in C:\Users\ewalds. That didnt work. Then I placed a bowerrc.txt in C:\Users\ewalds\AppData\config, which also did not work. The 3rd option I tried was placing the .bowerrc.txt file into my project folder, but that also did not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It should be named .bowerrc and not .bowerrc.txt. You will not be able to rename it to .bowerrc from Windows explorer. Instead open the command prompt and rename the file from there.

Comment: you can name the file in windows explorer to ".bowerrc." then it works, the dot at the end will be removed by windows.

Comment: @drorb: In what order these files (.bowerrc) are read. Lets say I have .bowerrc file located at `current working dir`, in my `home` folder & at `%APPDATA%/bower/config`. Which file will get preference? or will they get merged?

Comment: @SharpCoder The config is obtained by merging multiple configurations by this order of importance. The order is specified in the link I gave in the answer (starting from local files to global files)

Comment: @drorb: Thank you for quick reply. So the bowerrc file located @ `%APPDATA%/bower/config` will get the highest preference & it will overwrite any duplicate entry ?

Comment: @SharpCoder actually the other way around. The file at %APPDATA%/bower/config is the last in order