# Can't install Angular pack with Bower: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE Request

Tags: angularjs, git, bower

I try to install Angular pack from Git in Bower for my visual studio project, but i get this error:

> "bower  UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE Request to
>   https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular failed: unable to verify
>   the first certificate"

[image]

What is is this?! Why?!

Comment: Just a heads up, might be 'angular-latest' you're after, angular doesn't contain 'angular.js' / 'angular.min.js'

Comment: no, this isn't incorrect.

Comment: I wasn't posting a solution to your problem :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750804/bower-calls-blocked-by-corporate-proxy

Answer (score 9):

In your `.bowerrc` file put following :

```
{
    "strict-ssl": false
}
```

Then run `bower` command