# AngularJS e2e tests protractor setup

Tags: c#, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to setup end2end Angular Testing with Protractor in Visual Studio in.NET application but getting following error. What are these and how to get rid of these. How can i get rid of these and is there any way i can install protractor without Npm?

```
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "protractor"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Mandeep\MyStore\Application\MyStore.Web.Hos
t
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are behind a proxy. You can look at the following post to configure it :

[bower behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705091/bower-behind-a-proxy)

And it "may" be possible to use protactor (modulo the resolution of other dependencies) without npm by downloading and copying the protractor sources in a node_modules folder

https://github.com/angular/protractor/archive/master.zip