# Visual Studio 2015 bower configuration & proxy settings?

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015

I am running visual studio 2015 behind a proxy, for that reason bower is failing to install packages. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705091/bower-behind-a-proxy)
, I have put the proxy settings in `.bowerrc` file and placed this file on the root of the project, but still package restore is timing out.

I have tried similar situation with webstorm projects and it worked. Also, noticed that npm package pick up the IE proxy, so no need of extra configuration.

In short:

1. How can we set the proxy configuration for bower in visual studio project?
2. Is there a way to set the proxy configuration globally for bower?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035962/how-do-i-configure-bower-with-visual-studio/32035963#32035963

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding `.bowerrc` file on the project root directory next to `bower.json` file, so it looks like Bower can be configured just as you described. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6.

I also had to add the same proxy settings to Git, e.g:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Comment: where is the git.exe do do this?  When I just start a command line (or even a VS command line) git isn't a known command.  When I run the version at: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git" it says unsupported command argument.

Comment: I think you can't do that with git.exe
You must install git on your machine (first install node.js then install npm and finally install git).
Yeah it sucks.  You wan't probably not install all of this.  But after that, this command will works and set the proxy settings for you.

Comment: A solution exists without any extra installation. For more details, check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34182143/1152632).

Answer (score 0):

For me, bower was not able to download the package and gave me a ECMDERR error.

I ran the bower command related to downloading the package from the visual studio web tools folder and the error message has to do something with Git.

So I’ve decided to install Git from my visual studio installation and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the root folder locate .bowerrc file next to bower.json file and add these two properties:

```
 {
   ...
    "proxy": "http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080",
    "https-proxy": "http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080"
 }
```

put your proxy in those two properties.