# How do I configure bower with Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, bower, bower-install

As complexity of my web project is growing, I am realizing that downloading external JavaScript libraries manually, is error prone, time consuming and making project less maintainable over time.

Although Visual Studio has NuGet package manager, it is not as powerful as bower. Also not all external libraries are being released on NuGet.

But there is no clear help on how to configure bower with Visual Studio. Please help !

Answer (score 14):

[image]

As complexity of my web project grew, I realized that downloading external JavaScript libraries manually, was error prone, time consuming and made project less maintainable over time.

Although Visual Studio has NuGet package manager, it is not as powerful as bower. Also not all external libraries are being released on NuGet.

So, I decided to take the plunge and get started with bower.

My project structure is now much cleaner and easy to maintain.

---

Here I am listing steps, we need to take to configure bower with Visual Studio.

Detailed steps to use bower are already available on http://bower.io/#install-bower. Here I will list steps, I took to

- — install bower
- — configure it with Visual Studio
- — download a sample package -- ( AngularJS )

---

Bower requires node, npm and git for windows.

Before proceeding ahead, install the following

- git for windows – install from https://msysgit.github.io/
- node – install from https://nodejs.org/
- npm is part of node (no need for any extra step)

---

**Step# 1**

Open Command Prompt and execute command

`npm install -g bower`

[image]

> Above step may fail, if you are behind corporate proxy server. To add
>   proxy server settings in npm, execute following 2 commands from
>   command prompt
>
> `npm config set proxy http://proxy.myCompany.com:80`
>
> `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.myCompany.com:80`
>
> Once done, try installing
>   bower again

---

**Step# 2**

Navigate to your Visual Studio Project folder from Command Prompt.

Execute command

```
bower init
```

[image]

- Include this file to Visual Studio project. You may have to click on
  “Show All Files” from Solution Explorer menu.

[image]

---

**Step# 3**

Create a .bowerrc file using notepad with following configuration and save it in your Visual Studio Project folder

```
{
"directory": "scripts/bower_components",
"proxy":"http://proxy.myCompany.com:80",
"https-proxy":"http://proxy.myCompany.com:80"
}
```

- Include this file to Visual Studio project.
- Edit this file to set directory for packages to be downloaded by
  bower
- Add proxy server settings if you are working behind corporate proxy. Else remove the last 2 lines for proxy and https-proxy

[image]

---

**Step# 4**

To download AngularJs, execute command

```
bower install angular –save
```

This will add a line in bower.json.

### [image]

**Step# 5**

Package will be downloaded under bower_components directory by default. (or under the directory mentioned in .bowerrc file)

Make to sure include the whole package directory in Visual Studio project.

- Click on Show All Files
- Right click on new downloaded package and click on “Include in
  Project”

[image]

### [image]

**Step# 6**

Finally add reference of new package to your index.html

### [image]

---

Comment: 6 steps and still not nearly the same functionality I get with Nuget... I really don't see how this is better or more powerful... unless more powerful means "feels like hitting myself with a hammer."

Comment: Hi Matthew - For certain Javascript libraries that I was interested in (like Angular UI Grid), were NOT available in nuGet. Hence I chose to use bower. There are several more reasons why bower is being used for managing external Javascript libraries dependencies these days. You can refer to this link  - http://simplyaprogrammer.com/2014/06/why-bower-is-better-than-nuget.html

Comment: With, ASP.NET 5 and Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft will be using Bower as a client-side package manager. That means that packages like jQuery, Bootstrap and Angular will no longer be referenced using NuGet. More details are available at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/02/17/using-bower-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx  . So all these 6 manual steps will NOT be needed in Visual Studio 2015. Bower support will be in built.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Just compare the number of packages in bowler with client library packages in NuGet...

Comment: Just compare the mess that bower makes to your project.

Comment: So how do I set the proxy settings for bower globally without having to do that by creating a .bowerrc file manually for every blasted project?

Comment: Worked it out. .bowerrc file can be located in located in user’s home folder (~) c:\users\<username> on windows.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I also needed to configure git to use the proxy server :

git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxyURL:8080

After that bower worked in VS 2015