# Bower gets stuck in OSX

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am trying to install `angularjs` using bower in `OSX el-captain`. When I run bower install, it outputs a few lines like:

```
bower cached        git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower validate      3.3.6 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
```

but then becomes stuck. I tried the verbose option as well, in the hope that I will get more information but the output remains the same.

Any ideas why it is getting stuck??

Thanks.

Comment: how long did you wait to find out it was stuck?

Comment: 30 minutes. On my windows machine, with the exact same bower.json file, the script finishes in 5 minutes.

Comment: LOL okay I think there's a problem for sure...

Comment: what's your version of node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, try this fix, it will use https method instead of git method.

`git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://`

Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your system might be blocking while downloading the packages from git by bower because of few proxy settings. so In your .bowerrc file you need to give proxy configurations.

This link might help you!
[bower behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705091/bower-behind-a-proxy)

here is the example .bowerrc file:

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components",
  "proxy":"your proxy http url",
    "https-proxy":"http://<username>:<password>@<your proxy>"
}
```

in the above settings you need to replace with your information.