# bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads > git@github.om:mobify/bellows.git", exit code of #128

Tags: github, bower-install, mobify, mobify-js

I am trying to install the pinny1.0 plugin using bower as:

> bower install https://github.com/mobify/pinny.git#pinny-1.0

But meanwhile installing the plugin, I am getting issues as:

> bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
>   git@github.com:mobify/bellows.git", exit code of #128
>
> Additional error details: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I am not sure how this is redirecting from pinny1.0 to bellows.git.

I have tried to check the issue on Github bug tracking and find some discussion at #[1426](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1426)
but did not get much idea as I am not working on some proxy server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had The same Problem with Install `packages` using `Bower`.

This Problem happen because `bower proxy configuration`, you need to make `bower` use `http://` Instead of `git://` when install `packages`. you can Solve this problem using `.bowerrc` File.

**Just** create `.bowerrc` File and set `proxy` and `https-proxy` configuration :

```
{
  "proxy" : "http://<host>:<port>",
  "https-proxy" : "http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

More About [Bower Documentation](http://bower.io/docs/config/)  for `.bowerrc` File

There Two Questions about `bower proxy configuration` in StackOverflow :
[First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359887/bower-proxy-configuration) , [second Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705091/bower-behind-a-proxy)

**Update**:

IF the First Solution Does not Work, you can try suggest [@thebignet](https://github.com/thebignet) into same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/467#issuecomment-21482598)

Set `proxy`, `https-proxy` and `strict-ssl` configuration into  `.bowerrc` File :

```
{
  "proxy"       : "http://<host>:<port>",
  "https-proxy" : "http://<host>:<port>",
  "strict-ssl"  : false
}
```

**But** you must run Command from terminal:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: It may be a basic question but where to I put the .bowerrc file?

Comment: @VincentGauthier put `.bowerrc` file into root path for your app folder Like `bower.json` file and `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed an odd error. Interestingly, the git URL looks malformed.

```
git@github.om:mobify/bellows.git
```

There's no 'c' in .com. It is also weird that pinny is trying to pull bellows in; they're totally unrelated.

Could you let me know what OS and version of bower you're using?

I'll try to reproduce this and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Hi Steve sorry that is a typo and the URL is github.com:mobify.  On the other hand, the OS is windows 7 pro x64. I am doing it using the git bash not by any browser. I am also wondering that why installing pinny is related to the bellows? May be due to some internal dependencies ? Also FYI, I have the updated bellows installed already inside the bower_plugins of mu application.

Comment: It shouldn't be related at all. In fact, I can't seem to reproduce this issue on OSX or windows, so I'm a bit confused. Can you post your bower.json?