# Bower + Git submodules + Docker compose

Tags: git, docker, bower, docker-compose

I have 6 git sub-modules each with their own `Dockerfile`. I've setup my `docker-compose.yml` in this format:

```
a:
  build: A
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"

b:
  build: B
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"

c:
  build: C
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
```

A couple of my `Dockerfiles` have a step for bower to install the dependencies, but when this happens it errors out with the following message:

> bower open-sans#~1.1.0         resolve
>   git://github.com/bungeshea/open-sans.git#~1.1.0 bower
>   foundation#~5.5.1        ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote
>   --tags --heads git://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git", exit code of #128 fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/C
>
> Additional error details: fatal: Not a git repository:
>   ../.git/modules/C Service 'web' failed to build: The command
>   '/bin/sh -c npm install   && npm install -g bower   && bower install
>   --allow-root   && npm install -g gulp   && gulp build' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Seems that the command:
'/bin/sh -c npm install && npm install -g bower && bower install --allow-root && npm install -g gulp && gulp build'
should be replaced with:
'/bin/sh -c "npm install && npm install -g bower && bower install --allow-root && npm install -g gulp && gulp build"'

Comment: See https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1106

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using bower inside a Docker container, which was composed with docker-compose. This workaround did it for me (although this is not really satisfying):

```
GIT_DIR=/tmp bower install --allow-root
```

This [pull request](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1106) should fix it, but has not been merged yet.

Comment: @n20 - think I got it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It manually sets the tempory directory which git should use. Seems like this does not work out-of-the-box within a docker container. GIT_DIR sets the environment variable just for this command.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've tried this already but try running the following command:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

If this don't work you could try to configure the proxy/ports in the `.bowerrc` file.

Found some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/how-to-fix-bower-ecmderr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916640/bower-ecmderr-failed-to-execute-git-ls-remote-tags-heads-gitgithub-ommo)