# bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://gith ub.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git"

Tags: git, windows-10, bower, bower-install

I got this error when running:

```
bower install
```

[image: bower ECMDERR]

I've tried this:
[How to fix bower ECMDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/how-to-fix-bower-ecmderr)
and this:
[bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads > git@github.om:mobify/bellows.git", exit code of #128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916640/bower-ecmderr-failed-to-execute-git-ls-remote-tags-heads-gitgithub-ommo)

Their problem is different, because, in my problem, Git is using https instead of git. It's not been used proxy, neither It's in a corporate network.

I've tested in these environments:

Windows: 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1, 8.1 Single Language, 10 Pro.

Node: 4.4.3, 5.10.0, 6.0.0

npm 3.8.3

git version 2.8.1.windows.1

bower 1.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did so many things, so I'm not sure what's the appropriate solution. But these were:

1. Adding a SSH Key:
   https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/
2. Update npm: `npm install -g npm`.
3. Install gulp: `npm install -g gulp`.
4. Install Python.
5. Do this: `npm ls graceful-fs`.
6. With Windows 10 there were less problems.