# How can I get bower install working behind proxy?

Tags: npm, bower

I have set (I think) all the proxy settings for windows and npm works. However bower does not, this is the error I am getting:

```
  download https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.4.tar.gz
     retry Download of https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.4.tar.gz failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 1.7s
     retry Download of https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.4.tar.gz failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 2.2s
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink...
```

The file that displays after unlink does not even exist.

Bower version: 1.5.3
Node version: 4.1.1
OS: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 x64.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: **https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#https-proxy**

In your `.bowerrc`, you can add the following properties:

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
```

Here's also an example that includes user and password authentication fr the proxy (if that's the case):

```
"proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>"
```

Also, have a look at this question on Stack:
**[bower proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359887/bower-proxy-configuration)**